# Chrome, MSE increasing buffer?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, video

I'm looking for a way to increase video/audio buffer MSE is using.

My media keeps pausing/resuming due to slow connection:

Playing:

```
audio_buffering_state   {"state":"BUFFERING_HAVE_ENOUGH"}
dimensions  "1920x804"
duration    6988.2307
event   "kPlay"
info    "D3D11VideoDecoder is using array texture"
kAudioDecoderName   "FFmpegAudioDecoder"
kAudioTracks    [{"bytes per channel":4,"bytes per frame":8,"channel layout":"STEREO","channels":2,"codec":"mp3","codec delay":529,"discard decoder delay":true,"encryption scheme":"Unencrypted","has extra data":false,"profile":"unknown","sample format":"Float 32-bit","samples per second":48000,"seek preroll":"0us"}]
kFrameTitle "Movies"
kFrameUrl   xxx
kFramerate  24
kIsAudioDecryptingDemuxerStream false
kIsPlatformAudioDecoder false
kIsPlatformVideoDecoder true
kIsVideoDecryptingDemuxerStream false
kRendererName   "RendererImpl"
kResolution "1920x804"
kTextTracks []
kVideoDecoderName   "D3D11VideoDecoder"
kVideoPlaybackFreezing  0.025359
kVideoPlaybackRoughness 7.281
kVideoTracks    [{"alpha mode":"is_opaque","codec":"h264","coded size":"1920x804","color space":"{primaries:BT709, transfer:BT709, matrix:BT709, range:LIMITED}","encryption scheme":"Unencrypted","has extra data":false,"hdr metadata":"unset","natural size":"1920x804","orientation":"0°","profile":"h264 high","visible rect":"0,0 1920x804"}]
origin_url  xxx
pipeline_buffering_state    {"for_suspended_start":false,"state":"BUFFERING_HAVE_ENOUGH"}
pipeline_state  "kPlaying"
player_id   0
render_id   1759
seek_target 2922.002022
url xxx
video_buffering_state   {"state":"BUFFERING_HAVE_ENOUGH"}
```

Then pausing for some seconds:

```
audio_buffering_state   {"reason":"DEMUXER_UNDERFLOW","state":"BUFFERING_HAVE_NOTHING"}
dimensions  "1920x804"
duration    6988.2307
event   "kPlay"
info    "D3D11VideoDecoder is using array texture"
kAudioDecoderName   "FFmpegAudioDecoder"
kAudioTracks    [{"bytes per channel":4,"bytes per frame":8,"channel layout":"STEREO","channels":2,"codec":"mp3","codec delay":529,"discard decoder delay":true,"encryption scheme":"Unencrypted","has extra data":false,"profile":"unknown","sample format":"Float 32-bit","samples per second":48000,"seek preroll":"0us"}]
kFrameTitle "Movies"
kFrameUrl   xxx
kFramerate  24
kIsAudioDecryptingDemuxerStream false
kIsPlatformAudioDecoder false
kIsPlatformVideoDecoder true
kIsVideoDecryptingDemuxerStream false
kRendererName   "RendererImpl"
kResolution "1920x804"
kTextTracks []
kVideoDecoderName   "D3D11VideoDecoder"
kVideoPlaybackFreezing  0.025359
kVideoPlaybackRoughness 7.281
kVideoTracks    [{"alpha mode":"is_opaque","codec":"h264","coded size":"1920x804","color space":"{primaries:BT709, transfer:BT709, matrix:BT709, range:LIMITED}","encryption scheme":"Unencrypted","has extra data":false,"hdr metadata":"unset","natural size":"1920x804","orientation":"0°","profile":"h264 high","visible rect":"0,0 1920x804"}]
origin_url  xxx
pipeline_buffering_state    {"for_suspended_start":false,"reason":"DEMUXER_UNDERFLOW","state":"BUFFERING_HAVE_NOTHING"}
pipeline_state  "kPlaying"
player_id   0
render_id   1759
seek_target 2922.002022
url xxx
video_buffering_state   {"state":"BUFFERING_HAVE_ENOUGH"}
```

You can see this is clearly a buffer problem, if I can have a bigger buffer, it can survive a lot more bandwidth problems, as the media is `h264`-based, we can assume it's not CBR-encoded, so a buffer can could highly increase the media experience. I can sacrifice some initial or buffering delay / latency for sure.

How can I change MSE's media buffer sizes in Chrome under Windows?

Comment: What is "MSE" ?

Comment: Media Source Extensions. All modern browsers are using this technology for video/audio playback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Media Source Extensions](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/)
is a standard for browser API that is implemented today in all
the major browsers via JavaScript functions that are published
by the browser.

You will find a good example of a minimal player in the
[webpage](https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/bufferAll.html)
by Nick Desaulniers, and you may download the
[source](https://github.com/nickdesaulniers/netfix/blob/gh-pages/demo/bufferAll.html)
for further study.

The major objects taking part in the video flow are best explained
via the following diagram:

[image]

The major elements whose size you may wish to modify are the
[MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource)
and the
[SourceBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SourceBuffer).

However, if you examined the API calls for both these functions, you would
see that, astoundingly perhaps, there is nowhere to be found a buffer-size
parameter. Actually, this is by design. Your only option is in your
JavaScript player to ask the MediaSource object for buffers and to append
them to the SourceBuffer buffer.

In the article
[Exceeding the buffering quota](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/quotaexceedederror)
from 2019, Joseph Medley has examined the question of how much data can the
SourceBuffer object contain before it gives an error.
His findings per browser were:

[image]

Conclusion: The MSE internal cache is programmed into the browser
and cannot be modified. The only option is for the JavaScript player
to do the caching itself by asking for and appending more buffers
to the SourceBuffer object. However, I haven't seen such an option
in any of the web players I happened to use.

(The above discussion does not pertain to HTML5 video, for which there
is also no parameter for buffer-size.)

Comment: I have created once a JavaScript player which handles this perfectly, but I hoped that *Chrome* or *FF* is having some hidden setting deep inside which can tune the cache size. Thank you anyway, nice summary!

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox disable `media.mediasource.enabled` by setting to `false`. Then set `media.cache_readahead_limit` to `9999` and `media.cache_resume_treshold` also to `9999`. This settings set how much seconds of playback is pre-loaded by default. All Youtube videous are loaded 100% and in less then second for 2h+ video (with my internet speed, anyway). I'm not sure why you would even want MSE on if it makes video buffering so slow and retarded. How can modern web standart have miniscule max buffer of 150 MB? What is this, year 2000?